# Lock table for the other user

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem about locking table for other user in SQL server

I also read the official SQL Server documentation  and I have a queries as below:

```
Select * from ABC with(TABLOCKX)
```

Then I tested in my SQL server
I tested as below:
I create two transactions
Transction 1:

```
begin tran
    Select * from ABC with(TABLOCKX)
    waitfor delay '00:00:30';
commit;
```

Transction 2:

```
begin tran
 update ABC
 set demo = '0'
commit;
```

When I execute Transaction 1 and then I execute Transaction 2 immediately. (I am using the same user)
I found that Transaction 2 doesn't execute immediately. After Transaction 1 complete then I can  execute Transaction 2.

In sort I want to lock table in during transaction for other user. The same user still update table in this transaction.

I also found some other method . For example UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK. But all of them still lock table with the same user.
Can everyone help me this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Locks aren't user based, they're connection based. What are you *really* trying to achieve here as this smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Adding to @Larnu's comment, the implication is that all activity for the "user" must occur on the same connection and transaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know that. But because there are many users connect to the same connection.  I worry about that i and other user excute queries at the same time. So I want lock table that i  am executing in my transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific option to lock data per the user. All isolation levels work for the connection.

Per the definition of **Isolation Levels**:

> Controls the locking and row versioning behavior of Transact-SQL
> statements issued by a connection to SQL Server.

If you want to prevent multiple updates should try to find the best isolation level in your case. You should try `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. This isolation level prevents non repetable and phantom reads.

More information you can find here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15